# ID generation for HTML elements in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to generate unique identifiers for html elements in asp.net mvc application. 
In classic asp.net i could use

```
<a id=<%=ClientID>%>
```

Is there some analog in asp.net mvc world ?

**UPDATE:**

For example, I want to make a reusable Button element. I would perfer code to look similar to

```
<div class="myButton" id="<%=ClientID%>">
<script>
  var button = document.getElementById(<%=ClientID%>);
  button.onclick = ....
</script>
```

If ClientId is not available then what is the best way to follow ?
For now, I see two options - to generate it like **Guid.NewGuid()** or pass id from the outside ? Any other options ?

**UPDATE:**
For now, I've come to following solution

```
    public static string UniqueId(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        var idGenerator = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[typeof (UniqueIdGenerator)] as UniqueIdGenerator;
        if (idGenerator==null)
            html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[typeof (UniqueIdGenerator)] = idGenerator = new UniqueIdGenerator();
        return idGenerator.Next();
    }
       ...
    private class UniqueIdGenerator
    {
        private int id;

        public string Next()
        {
            id++;
            return "_c" + id; // todo: optimize
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, you couldn't.  `<a id=<%=ClientID>%>` will not generate unique IDs.

Comment: Hi Alex, your question makes sense to me and I understand this, but I can't answer because I am new to MVC as well. Anyway, can you explain why do you need this in case somebody would have an idea on how to get the same as what you would like to do differently?

Comment: It looks like you're very used to the webforms way of doing things, but I recomend you take another look at your problem and see if you can try something else, you just have to think differently. If you tell us what your real problem is we might be able to help you more. But if you just want Id's use a random number and a name string. That's all id's are, well appart from plus naming containers, but it's mvc so we don't need those.

Comment: control.ClientID doesn't generate IDs it returns the value of the generated client id

Answer (score 20):

**Simplest correct solution using built-in .NET libraries with no new custom application code required**

Use Guid.NewGuid(), with the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) numeric representation "N" in order to prevent invalid characters that could browser JS issues.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

Quoting MSDN regarding the `"N"` format specifier:

`32 digits: 00000000000000000000000000000000`

Don't use the default GUID representation as hyphens can be problematic to work with in JS/jQuery.

For completeness, it's best prepend a letter to the beginning of the GUID. Although I've never experienced issues with this in modern browsers, [technically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) an HTML `id` has to begin with a letter and not a number.

Comment: Great solution. This is a rather trivial task that MVC really should take care of itself you if want it to.

Comment: May I recommend your example includes the alpha prefix?
`$"a{Guid.NewGuid():N}"`

Answer (score 1):

There is no single solution to this.

You need to modify your code to generate IDs based on whatever is generating the elements.

For example, if you're looping over rows from a database, you can use the rows' primary keys to generate IDs.

Alternatively, you can eschew IDs altogether and use non-unique classes.  (this is especially convenient with jQuery and descendant selectors)

Answer (score 1):

I liked the answer you provided in your Update better than using a `Guid`, because the latter will be different each time which makes client-side debugging and finding an element in View Source more difficult.

I took it a step further and added a custom `prefix`.. each `prefix` uses its own counter to help even further in that regard.

```
    public static string GetUniqueHtmlid(this HtmlHelper html, string prefix)
    {
        var generator = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[typeof (UniqueHtmlIdGenerator)] as UniqueHtmlIdGenerator;

        if(generator == null)
            html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[typeof(UniqueHtmlIdGenerator)] = generator = new UniqueHtmlIdGenerator();

        return generator.GetNextUniqueId(prefix);
    }

    private class UniqueHtmlIdGenerator
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _items = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public string GetNextUniqueId(string prefix)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
                prefix = "item";

            int current;

            lock (typeof (UniqueHtmlIdGenerator))
            {
                current = _items.ContainsKey(prefix) ? _items[prefix] : 1;

                _items[prefix] = current + 1;
            }

            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", prefix, current);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

May be this draft code help you:

```
static class MyIdGenerator
{
    public static int NextID()
    {
        static int _id = 0;
        return _id++;
    }
}
```

With static counter every call `NextID()` will return next Id;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but code like this can fail if called from multiple threads. Imagine one client sending two ajax requests :)

Comment: Yes, it code not thread safe and can generate unexpected sequence. I think that need refactoring code to avoid use generated id. In MVC paradigm no need use id like this code because it wrong to map model properties. In MVC can use html templates for complex types and collections to map to it - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MVC+collections+in+model

Comment: The correct thread safe implementation is: static class MyIdGenerator { private static int _id; public static int NextId() { return System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _id); } }