# Bootstrap 4 modal div with ID (Guid from C# model)

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog, partial-views

So basically if I go with:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model.ID">
<div class="modal fade" id="@Model.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CenterTitle"" aria-hidden="true">
```

it does **not** work! (ID is public Guid ID { get; set; })
The button does not open the modal window.

If I manually change to something like

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#id11">
<div class="modal fade" id="id11" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CenterTitle"" aria-hidden="true">
```

it works? Any idea?

Comment: What is the actual value of `@Model.ID`. What is showing if you place it somewhere else?

Comment: it is different but something like Guid.NewGuid() or "0a757770-02dd-4dbd-972e-9a307174224b"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492433/id-generation-for-html-elements-in-asp-net-mvc does that work? Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the Guid value sometimes starts with a number and that's a problem for CSS.

Comment: That would have taken me hours to find...